# Inserting a background-image

Tags: custom-background

I would like all my site pages to have a background-image, such as:

```
body {
  background-image: url(https://5e97-e8af726b4e97.wptiger.fr/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/images/header.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Using additional CSS field does not work.
What can be the solution, please?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your CSS is OK, (I am not an expert at CSS but I am currently learning it myself).

I think you issue is a cerficate error on the page you are hosting

try this:

```
body {background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-600w-1389188336.jpg");
        background-size:cover;}
```

I tested it in the additional CSS on my page and it worked.

I also added it to my stylesheet in my child theme and that also worked.

Hope that helps!

Cheers.